# How to format the PBI shows apostrophe instead whole content

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to minimize the words appear in my PowerBI table.
eg: I have one of my columns shows

| name |
| --- |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |

and I want to format this column to look like this

| name |
| --- |
| aaa... |

I have tried reduce the size of this column but instead it shows

| name |
| --- |
| aaaa |
| aaaa |
| aaaa |

Once my mouse moves onto it, it will appear the whole content
How could I format this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this **calculated column** to your table:

```
short name = RIGHT('Table'[name], 3) & "..."
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: i want to show the full content when my cursor moves on the column   so i guess this wont work.  im pretty sure its something related to formatting

Comment: You ask for the impossible.

Comment: You could put short name in the visual and name in a tooltip, or a report tooltip page.